# Mapping entity without key

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I've got two tables in database: Table A (parent) has a primary key column and Table B (child) doesn't have a key at all, but references to the key in table A (parent).

The column aID (not a primary/foreign key) refererences to the id in table A (parent).

[image]

I've tried to use a composite key in table B, but without any success:

**Mappings:**

```
 public AMap() 
 {
    Id(a=> a.Id);
    Map(a=> a.Name);
    HasMany(a=> a.B)
       .Cascade.All();
 }

 public BMap() 
 {
    CompositeId()
       .KeyReference(b=> b.A, "aID");
    Map(b=> b.Name);
    Map(b=> b.Year);
 }
```

**Entity A properties:**

```
 private int _id;
 public virtual int Id
 {
     get { return _id; }
     set { _id = value; }
 }

 private string _name;
 public virtual string Name
 {
     get { return _name; }
     set { _name = value; }
 }

 private IList<B> _b;
 public virtual IList<B> B
 {
     get { return _b; }
     set { _b= value; }
 }
```

**Entity B properties:**

```
 private int _aid;
    public virtual int AID
    {
        get { return _aid; }
        set { _aid = value; }
    }

    private A _a;
    public virtual A A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a= value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name= value; }
    }

    private string _year;
    public virtual string Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set { _year= value; }
    }
```

**I've also tried Component:**

```
 public BMap() 
 {
   Id(); 
   Component(b => b.A, bb => 
   { 
     bb.Map(a => a.Id).Column("aID"); 
   });
 }
```

But then i get following exceptions:

Invalid column name 'A_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'A_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'id'.

could not initialize a collection: [TestProject.Test.A.B#7][SQL: SELECT b0_.A_id as A5_1_, b0_.id as id1_, b0_.id as id90_0_, b0_.Name as Name90_0_, b0_.Year as Year3_90_0_, b0_.aID as aID90_0_ FROM [Test.B] b0_ WHERE b0_.A_id=?]

The B list does not get populated when im getting all a:s from database, does anyone see something wrong in this code or have a better solution than using a Composite key ? Is it possible to let nhibernate use an identifier only in application layer ?
I'm not able to change data model in database.

EDIT: Added exceptions and mapping with Component instead.

Comment: If aID is not a foreign key, then what is it? if it is referencing ID then it is already a foreign key, whether you name it a foreign key or not.

Comment: It is referencing to A's id. But its not a primary/foreign key column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a "**Component**".
In nhibernate there are three "types": Entities, Components and Primitives. Entities should have identifiers and ID columns period. Because for example you will consider two Entities are different even if their data are the same. They point to different instances. 
If the item doesn't have a entity semantic, it behaves like value type, then you should use a component. Components will not require an ID column for them selves and they behave as Value type.

Comment: I've tried using Component instead, but without any success :         Id();
            Component(b => b.A, bb =>
            {
                bb.Map(a => a.Id).Column("aID");
            });